# Nodes.js post parameters

Tags: node.js, http

1) Why is it that when i try to get parameters from a post request in node.js
i get the correct values.

```
app.post('/users', function(req, res) {

  console.log(">>> " + req.param('name')); ' works but with warnings
  res.send("ok");


});
```

The above sample outputs a warning that this "param" function is deprecated and i should use params.name. using params.name is acutally not working and results in "undefined", the same with body.name.

this happens also when i use

```
router.post('/',function(req, res, next) {

  console.log("result > " + req.params.name); ' result is "undefined"
  res.send(req.body);
});
```

i've included bodyparser with json support.

Am i missing something or what exactly i'm doing wrong?

2) Furthermore is there a way to get all parameters without naming them? both for get/post requests?

Comment: have you tried body parser with urlencoded? i.e. `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))` ?

Comment: yes i tried it, unfortunatly without success!

Answer (score 2):

after trying again and again i found it:

the post request may NOT be multipart encoded - so if 
enctype="multipart/form-data" is set, remove it or change it to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

after removing the enctype i tried to get the data with

```
var result = req.body.name
```

which worked.

for multipart encoded posts you've to use "multer" i guess!

> > > EDIT

i just found out that

```
req.params.name
```

is only for urls parts e.g.

http://host:port/application/name

and the documentation clearly says that in express 4.x you've to use
"use a multipart-handling middleware like busboy, multer, formidable, multiparty, connect-multiparty, or pez." (http://expressjs.com/api.html#router.route)